# Crystal Report not showing data from SQL Server 17.5

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

After creating a table and putting data in it in the previous form, this form tries to display the report, but I am getting a blank report. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my VB 2017 code for form load event:

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Public Class Form5
    Private Sub Form5_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
        cryRpt.Load("C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\WindowsApp3\WindowsApp3\CrystalReport4.rpt")
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
        CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem in the following way

Here is my modified VB 2017 code for form load event:

```
    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM monAtt"
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, conn1)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    conn1.Open()
    Dim MyDA As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
    MyDA.SelectCommand = cmd
    Dim myDS As New TestDataSet1()
    MyDA.Fill(myDS, "monAtt")
    Dim oRpt As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument()
    oRpt.Load("C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\WindowsApp3\WindowsApp3\CrystalReport4.rpt")
    oRpt.SetDataSource(myDS.Tables("monAtt"))
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = oRpt
    CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = True
    conn1.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
```